# mouseDragged: Not called in NSView subclass

Tags: cocoa, mouseevent, nsview

For a custom NSBox I have the following problem I can't get my mouseDragged to get called.

Knowing that : `mouseMoved:`, `mouseEntered:`, `mouseExited:`, `mouseUp` are  all called when needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem : `mouseDown:` has to be overridden in the subclass.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to implement a ```NSDragOperation``` on my ```NSButton```, none of the methods were called, until I implemented ```mouseDown``` (even though I don't need it). Thanks again :)